# How to use Autofac container to resolve an instance of a type?

Tags: windows-services, autofac

In a windows service, how should one get an instance of a class?

obviously new up an instance will defect the whole purpose of DI. in the old days, one would do

`ISomeInterface st =  container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();`

in this case, the class that implements `ISomeInterface` has a dependency class/interface in its contructor e.g. `SomeInterfaceImp(IOtherInterface oi)()`.

how to do this with autofac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty standard dependency resolution/automatic wire-up stuff. As long as you have all of your dependencies in the container, resolving `ISomeInterface` will automatically also chain in any dependencies like `IOtherInterface`.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeInterfaceImp>().As<ISomeInterface>();
builder.RegisterType<OtherInterfaceImp>().As<IOtherInterface>();
var container = builder.Build();
```

[There is a good getting started guide on Autofac with lots of examples on the Autofac doc site.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/index.html) I suggest you start there.

Note that if you are writing a long-running Windows service (as suggested by your tags) you should not resolve things out of the container because you may end up with a memory leak. [There is plenty of documentation about this as well.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. the reason I ask this question is that most of the example I find about autofac is that it's integrated into a framework. e.g. MVC/web api/webform, it's either use httphandler/filter to hook itself into the framework for DI, but for the rest of the programing structure like getting an instance of a certain class to do work in a windows service, it seems that one need to create a global reference of the container for use in the application it's very similar to the service locator pattern, which introduce a new dependency in this case.

Comment: In Windows Services, WinForms apps, and other apps where DI isn't baked into the framework, you are right - you get to integrate it manually yourself, with all the pros and cons that go along with it. There's no "recommended pattern" for that.

Comment: one issue with this it's the scope problem. let's say setting the instance per thread but when resolving the instance need to the following: using(var scope = container.BegineLifetimeScope()){ Isomeinterface instance = scope.Resolve<Isomeinterface>();} when the scope is disposed, it will dispose any instance that implements the IDiposable interface. this defeats the purpose of instance per thread/InstancePerLifetimeScope, wouldn't it?

Comment: You may need to either update your question or ask a new one. Not that I don't want to help, but the question, as written, has been answered and there is a lot of doc and overlapping existing questions/answers covering the additional topics it sounds like you're curious about. Dive into the Autofac doc site, look at the existing stuff on disposal and thread lifetime scopes, and if it's still unclear, open a new question here with more detail.

Comment: sure, I will give you the credit for the discussion.